# /V1/categories REST API petition retunring only 1 record

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.2

I'm using magento 2.1.2 and for some reason the GET petition to rest/V1/categories in my platform only returns "Default category" , but if i do a POST petition with an ID of other category it shows the category details , even when it doesnt appears in the list tree of all categories.

I've already flush the cache and same output.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that my other category it was outside default category so it wasnt showing in the petition, moved the category to Default Category and the problem was solved